# Image and Kernel of a certain bounded operator

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Consider and Hilbert Space $X$, $T\in B(X)$ and a scalar $\mu$ s.t. $|\mu|=||T||$

By a simple argument I deduced that $\ker(\mu I- T)=\ker(\bar\mu I-T^*$) where $*$ denotes the adjoint.

I am then asked to deduce that $ \text{Im} (\mu I - T) + \ker (\mu I - T)$ is dense in $X$.

It does not seem to me that this follows, I think we need, in addition, the image to be closed.

If anybody could indicate the reason why this holds true I would be extremely grateful!

Comment: Your operator is _bounded_. What do you know about the Image of a bounded operator?

Comment: @AlexR Not much, in infinite dimensions, if it was bounded below ($||(\mu I-T)x|| \geq c ||x||)$ then I could conclude, but I don't see why this should happen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, we have for any subspaces $A, B$ of a topological vector space $E$ the relation

$$\overline{A} + \overline{B} \subset \overline{A+B}.\tag{1}$$

Further, for any $S \in B(X)$, where $X$ is a Hilbert space, we have

$$\ker S^\ast = (\operatorname{im} S)^\perp.\tag{2}$$

Apply $(1)$ and $(2)$ to the right operator and subspaces to reach the conclusion.

Comment: Thanks, since it was an exercise on Spectral theory I was completely off track. So there is nothing particular about $\mu I - T$ and the same statement would hold for any bounded operator $S$ such that   $\ker S= \ker S^*$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is the required thing here. You get that for normal operators, or for non-normal ones, under the given condition.